# My site build fails in Netlify's CI environment. What should I do to debug?

Tags: netlify

My site build fails in [Netlify](http://www.netlify.com)'s CI environment. What should I do to debug?

Answer (score 0):

[Gatsby build failing on netlify #6138](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/6138) might help

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this behavior by unsetting the CI variable in your build. For example, the following will unset CI for the NPM command:

> CI= npm run build

1. Log in to Netlify
2. Choose your app and click on Site settings
3. Navigate to Build & Deploy
4. Under Continuous Deployment select Edit
   settings
5. Update Build command to

> CI= npm run build

If you are using netlify.toml to set the build command, update it as such:

> ...
> command = "CI= npm run build"
> ...

*Rebuild you deployment